# Failed to complete Gradle execution : cause

Tags: java, android, gradle

Error:Failed to complete `Gradle` execution.

Cause:

> Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program
>   Files\Android\Android
>   Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.14.1-all\8bnwg5hd3w55iofp58khbp6yv\gradle-2.14.1-all.zip.lck

I install android for the first time and I get this problem when I don't to start my first project. 
Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that `Android Studio` supports `Build.gradle` version 3.0+ so you need to change the version into the `build.gradle` file of your project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {

        //Android Studio 3.0
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    }
}
```